# Is migration needed from "old" onenote API to new microsoft graph api?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I've build a Java library to get the interaction of java application with Microsoft Onenote.

I recently discovered that the API has changed:

For getting a specific Sectionthe url was

- `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/SECTION_ID`

And is now:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/SECTION_ID`

Both are "v1.0" while both have a different signature :

- Onenote API:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections(parentNotebook(id,name,self),parentSectionGroup(id,name,self))/$entity",
   "id": "SECTION_ID",
   "self": "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/SECTION_ID",
   "createdTime": "2014-05-29T08:56:57.223Z",
   "name": "Adresses",
   "createdBy": "xxxx",
   "lastModifiedBy": "xxxx",
   "lastModifiedTime": "2014-06-10T12:55:22.41Z",
   "isDefault": false,
```

- Microsoft Graph API:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxx%40live.com')/onenote/sections/$entity",
    "id": "SECTION_ID",
    "self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@live.com/onenote/sections/SECTION_ID",
    "createdDateTime": "2014-05-29T08:56:57.223Z",
    "displayName": "Adresses",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2014-06-10T12:55:22.41Z",
    "isDefault": false,
    "pagesUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@live.com/onenote/sections/SECTION_ID/pages",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "id": "USER_ID",
            "displayName": "xxxx"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "id": "USER_ID",
            "displayName": "xxxx"
        }
    },
```

---

I wonder if I need to upgrade to Microsoft Graph API or if it safe to remain with the Onenote API.

I don't find any documentation about the migration. All the links pointing to the old url are now pointing to the new url...

Answer (score 0):

We encourage you to move to Microsoft Graph API because it has a single auth token for multiple services like OneNote, OneDrive, SharePoint, etc. But you *could* stay on the OneNote API and we still fully support it

Comment: Are there some documentation about the migration from OneNote API to the the Graph API ?

Comment: It is mostly 1:1 mapping...and the changes in the url segments are similar in all endpoints. Let us know if you don't find the equivalent MS Graph endpoint for any OneNote Api

Comment: It's important to note the POST file size limit in MS Graph endpoint is much smaller (4MB) vs (~70MB) for the Onenote Api. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592242/error-request-too-large-413-when-trying-to-upload-a-pdf-file-to-onenote